# Modify Timer Interrupt in Linux

Tags: linux, multithreading, timer, interrupt

At college I'm studying Operative Systems, and as a first part of the project we have to modify the Timer Interrupt to execute my own code, may be with threads, and I think that Linux present less restrictions to access the Interrupt Vector that Windows does, is not?

Can you give me more details if it's better use Windows or Linux (like Ubuntu) to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: If you're going to want to be poking around at the level of interrupt vectors at the very least I'd be looking to have the source code of the kernel available...

Comment: Typo in the question - operating systems

Answer (score 2):

I would use Linux, because I think you might fail your assignment if you use Windows. The reason being that the commonly accessible timers (i.e. non-driver stuff) under Windows are not really interrupts, they're messages posted to your thread's message queue.

Whereas under Linux signal/sigaction in combination with timer_create will send a signal, which really counts as "interrupt".